# AWS : Using Lambda for RDS replications

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

Can AWS Lambda functions subscribe to RDS (Oracle) events?  We have two RDS Oracle instances that we would like to replicate inserted and updated rows between.

We've tried Database Migration Tasks, but they fail on a regular basis. The logs some how get corrupted; we then have to truncate the destination tables and copy millions of records over again.

Comment: are you asking whether lambda can respond to RDS insert/update events?

Comment: The only AWS RDS database engine that supports triggering AWS Lambda functions natively is Aurora. You might be able to create triggers in your Oracle database that call stored procedures that then call the AWS API to invoke your Lambda functions. It sounds like you are trying to create a multi-master DB cluster, and I'm not sure either of these solutions (DB migration service, or Lambda) are the correct method of accomplishing that.

Comment: Have you ruled out GoldenGate?

Comment: [Madhukar] - Yes, that is correct.

[Mark] - The source database is the master db. The destination db uses a subset of data from several of the source tables

[Jarmod] - I'm not familar with GoldenGate, I will look into it

Comment: So I tried out Golden Gate and given the complexity of setup and perceived maintenance we would like to find a [simpler] solution.  This is a small part of a larger project and once it is all complete the customer will assume full custody and responsibility. They aren't a highly technical group of people and we believe the GG solution would likely be too much form them to maintain.

Is it possible to use a RDS Oracle instance as a Kinesis stream? I'm thinking we could write lambda functions to process the stream and insert new / updated records into the desitination RDS instance.

Comment: ...as a Kinesis stream 'source'